# Decimal date & time conversion

Tags: python

I've been given a pile of reports generated by someone who is no longer with us.
They each begin with a decimal date and time like this: "41433.662413","41401.250002"
I have tried many different methods using datetime and can't figure out how to recover the date. I know (because of a hand written note) that the above refers to 27th May 2013 6am.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What format are they in?

Comment: Which of the above refers the the 27th May? There's two there... Also, thinking about it, you need to know two dates in order to have a chance of working this out. 1 to work out what you think is accurate, the second to test it. If you don't have two you're left with guessing based on how realistic the outcomes are.

Comment: The first uses a decimal (.) as the separator, the second uses a comma (,). Is that by design or a typo?

Comment: Using excel, the second date gives May 7th, 2013 at 6:00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like OLE Automation dates, which is used in a many [systems such as Microsoft Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm).  It's effectively a floating point value representing the days, with a value of 1.0 equaling midnight on Jan. 1st, 1900.

You can convert to a python date via:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

d = timedelta(days=41433.662413)
st = datetime(1899,12,31)
date = st + d
print(date)
```

This will print `2013-06-09 15:53:52.483200`.  While this does differ from the May 27th date you mentioned, given that you included more than one input, I *suspect* this is the proper conversion, as this would be a standard which provides dates and times within the same range as your hand written note.  Without knowing exactly which input corresponds to that date, however, it would be difficult to tell.

May 27th, at 6am would be a value of `41420.25` using this conversion.  I would check for this "value" to check if the hand written note aligns with this format.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I've corrected the comma, it was a typo. The excel result is spot on. What formula was used? Can I use it in python? Thanks.

Comment: I have one other report for which I have the correct date: "41373.624205","41374.250001" This is definitely for 10th April 2013 I hope that helps. Once again thanks for your time.

Comment: @Floatingshed That works with the above - and reports 10th April.  In excel, you can just put in a date and format as a number to see these values.

Comment: Looks like you've cracked it Reed. Many thanks, that's a great help.